# access old username and change to use it on accounts

Tags: gmail

I can't access several accounts I created, probably because I didn't know what password I'd used, before the one I finally created.  I don't like that this last account I created is the one being used on my blog and on everything associated with Google.

How do I retrieve one of the other accounts and change my username associated with Google?